# Lync Server chat client API for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, chat, lync, lync-client-sdk

I have a consulting website (on ASP.NET MVC 4) that users should be able to text/voice chat, send files and pricing feature for any conversation.
I checked Microsoft Lync Server 2013 and it has all of these features but it works in enterprise domain. Also Lync SDK API is available but I'm not sure that this API can help me to create my own lync server client for all of our users or not?

**First** question is Lync SDK is suitable for my needs? 
and **Second** question, is there any open source or free library for ASP.NET MVC that have text/voice chat and file sharing?

any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Lync Client SDK isn't for websites. There are Silverlight controls available, but they will only work if the user has the Lync Client installed, which is probably not true for your website.

For text only chat, you could look at UCWA, but you'd have to handle file-sending yourself. There's currently nothing that can do voice in a browser, but UCJA/jLync was announced at the Lync Conference 2014 Keynote and should be able to do that.

I actually blogged about the different APIs available and what they are all for yesterday: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/07/lync-development-picking-the-right-api/